# Faulty ruby compilation with rvm: getting 'undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init' while running racku

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am on Ubuntu. Any ideas? Do I have to set any compilation option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're missing some devel packages on your system.  See my article [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm), specifically [this step](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux_3.htm).  I'm not sure, but the MD5 code could be part of libssl, so it would be covered by installing these packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libreadline5-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank yo so much!

Comment: You can also run "rvm requirements", like the tutorial says, to see all the dependencies required by RVM.