# "rails -d mysql newapp" gives: undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos5

```
# rails -d mysql newapp
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so: /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so: undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init - /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:16
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:14
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.3/bin/rails:8
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:19
[root@rapvdbs03 www]#
```

gives the same error if I take out the mysql option

Comment: related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init

Comment: I saw that and thought it might be, but that is ubuntu and rvm/racku, not rails. It was no help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rails3?

If so, then the syntax for creating a new app with mysql is the following:

```
rails new newapp -d mysql
```