# After setting up RVM and Ruby 187, getting this error of undefined symbol: rb_Digest_SHA1_Init on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-11.04

```
gourav@ubuntu$ bundle install

/home/gourav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/digest/sha1.so:

undefined symbol: rb_Digest_SHA1_Init - 

/home/gourav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/digest/sha1.so

gourav@ubuntu$ gem li

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.10)
actionpack (3.0.10)
activemodel (3.0.10)
activerecord (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.10)
activesupport (3.0.10)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.10)
railties (3.0.10)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
```

Comment: Possible duplucate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init

Comment: It is not I followed that link but not able to resolve this error from that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `rvm notes` and make sure to run whatever it tells you to, then recompile (`rvm install 1.8.7`) ruby.

Most likely, if you're on current RVM, you'll be told to do this:

```
apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev 
                curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev 
                libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev 
                autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake
```

Comment: I had upgraded to 1.9.2 locally then found my ISP didn't support it so I had to go back to 1.8.7 and do rebundling and stuff and had this error.  The piece about rvm install 1.8.7 is very true.  Even if it says 'already downloaded' it's the recompile that did it for me.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04.1, this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on a CentOS server that was not using rvm.  When running script/console, ruby would complain about **rb_Digest_SHA1_Init**.  When running script/server, ruby would complain about **rb_Digest_MD5_Init**.

After many rebuilds of ruby, and after installing (via yum) all the extra packages that this and other posts suggested, the thing that finally fixed it for me was the addition of  **--enable-pthread** when configuring the ruby build.

So,

Install all the devel tools suggested by Dylan Markow.  If using yum, run

```
yum search <name>
```

where  is a simplified version of 'ncurses-dev' or 'libxml2-dev'.  All other posts on the subject use apt-get, and that wasted a lot of time for me.

Rebuild ruby with the --enable-pthread param;

```
./configure --enable-pthread && make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error.
I tried to uninstall libssl-dev and it fixed this ... now my ruby has no ssl support whatsoever.