# getting undefined symbol: rb_Digest_SHA1_Init error on rbenv installed ruby 2.0.0-p195

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and using ruby 2.0.0-p195 enabled by rbenv v0.4.0.

when I run below,

```
$ruby -rdigest/sha1 -e '1'
```

I get this error.

```
/home/ktsuji/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': /home/ktsuji/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so: undefined symbol: rb_Digest_SHA1_Init - /home/ktsuji/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
from /home/ktsuji/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
```

I know this is really similar to issue described here:
[Faulty ruby compilation with rvm: getting 'undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init' while running racku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init)

but I've already tried the answer in above thread and ran below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libreadline6-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

and even tried reinstall:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g-dev libreadline6-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
$ (rbenv uninstall -f 2.0.0-p195 && rbenv install 2.0.0-p195)
```

but had no luck. I've also tried other ruby versions with rbenv:

- 1.8.7-p371 works fine.
- 1.9.3-p429 got similar error as above.

Any idea on resolving this issue?

Comment: You may need to install `libopenssl-ruby` as well.

Comment: I tried it after I installed libopenssl-ruby(which turned into libruby in ubuntu BTW), but still having same issue..

Comment: I tried this in clean installed machine with build-essential, libssl-dev installed and this error didn't occur. So I'm sure it's only happening in this particular environment, but it would be really great if I can fix this issue here.

Comment: Had similar issue, running it with sudo removes the error.