# "undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init" while running Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, runtime-error

I am trying to run Ruby On Rails, but every time I start it (even if I run `rails` without arguments, when it should display some help) it produces an error:

```
serge1peshcoff@myLaptop:~$ rails
/home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so: undefined symbol: rb_Digest_MD5_Init - /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/serge1peshcoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've faced the same error while installing `nokogiri` gem, but I solved it by using `--use-system-libraries`, it installed fine. I tried to install `rails` the same way, but it still doesn't work.

Also I tried to install `libssl-dev` (some googling led me to the SO question with the error the same as mine) but it was already installed.

I am using the latest version of `RVM` (1.26.11), `ruby` (2.2.3) and `rails` (4.2.4).

What can cause such an error?

UPD: I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init), it has the only answer telling me to install some packages, which didn't do the trick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faulty ruby compilation with rvm: getting 'undefined symbol: rb\_Digest\_MD5\_Init' while running racku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545118/faulty-ruby-compilation-with-rvm-getting-undefined-symbol-rb-digest-md5-init)

Comment: @dimakura I've seen this, it has the only answer telling me to install some packages, which didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my profile folder is messed up, because I tried to create new user and install `rvm` and `rails` after it, and everything worked fine.

UPD: it seems like something from `~/.config` caused the problem, because after removing some folders (can't tell exactly which one, because I removed a bunch of them at once) Rails finally started to work.